# cannot move file because of & in name

Tags: command-line, quoting

Trying to command

`mv foo&foo.jpg images/`

but get command not found, then if try and rename the file it won't let me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use single quotes. For example:

```
mv 'foo&foo.jpg' images/
```

Unless you quote or escape the `&` symbol, it's interpreted as a special token by the shell.

Answer (score 3):

One more way , use escape character

`mv file\&filename any`

That will rename `file&filename` named file into any name.

Answer (score -1):

This requires many steps but I would try this when every other option fails.

Lets say `foo&foo.jpg` is in `/a/b` along with other files, I would create `/a/b_new` and move all files there probably with multiple moves to match all the files but `foo&foo.jpg`.

Then run below commands: `cd /a;
cp /a/b/* /a/b_new/foo.jpg;
rm -r /a/b;
mv /a/b_new /a/b;`

Note: Some flavors might require `mv -i` or `mv -R` to rename directory.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Hmm, Read it one more time.